# STL algorithm to process first N elements which comply with condition

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I have a piece of code which iterates over a vector of coordinates. I then want to use first N coordinates from the vector which comply with a condition.
The approach (simplified):

```
Matrix image;
int maxCount = N;
std::vector<Point> coordinates(sizeof >> maxCount);
std::vector<SomeClass> filtered;
filtered.reserve(maxCount);
for (const auto& coordinate : coordinates)
    {
        if (image.at(coordinate) != 255)
        {
            continue;
        }

        filtered.emplace_back(coordinate, ...);

        // end when we have enought points
        if (filtered.size() == maxCount)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

What I would want is to avoid the for loop and use the STL library. Something roughly like this:

```
for_each_n_if(begin(v), N, [&](Point p){ 
 if(cond) {
      otherVec.emplace_back(p,...);
      return true; // help counter is incremented
 } else {return false;}});
```

Is there any function that might do that in stl? *(I did check, just wondering if I missed something not so obvious)*

Comment: Why?  Is the loop not readable?

Comment: Just trying to use stl whenever possible. I thought there might be some function dealing with this particular situation.

Comment: with [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) (and soon in [C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges)): `auto res = coordinates | ranges::view::filter([&](const auto& coordinate){ return image.at(coordinate) == 255; }) | ranges::view::take(maxCount);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most STL algorithms focus on one specific task, they do not compose well - this is why we will get ranges in the first place. Until then you either have to

1. split your intention into multiple algorithm calls,
2. write a specific algorithm for your use case
3. continue sticking with a manual loop (they can be pretty readable after all) or
4. use one the available range libraries.

---

One suggestion for 2., the specific algorithm:

```
template <class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt, class Pred, class Fct>
auto transform_n_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, Size count, OutputIt dest,
    Pred pred, Fct transform)
{
   Size n(0);

   while (first != last && n !=count) {
      if (pred(*first)) {
         *dest++ = transform(*first);
         ++n;
      }

      ++first;
   }

   return dest;
}
```

which is callable like this:

```
std::vector<Point> coordinates(someSize);
std::vector<SomeClass> filtered;

transform_n_if(coordinates.cbegin(), coordinates.cend(), 42, std::back_inserter(filtered),
      [](const Point& p){ return /* your condition here... */ true; },
      [](const Point& p){ return /* your transformation here... */ SomeClass(p); });
```

Comment: This considers `count` inputs, rather than stopping after `count` outputs

Comment: @Caleth: Easily fixed though, by incrementing `n` only if the predicate is true. (Done)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::all_of` and return `false` from the predicate when you want to stop:

```
std::all_of(coordinates.begin(), coordinates.end(),
            [&](const auto& coordinate)
            {
               if (image.at(coordinate) == 255)
                  filtered.emplace_back(coordinate, ...);
               return filtered.size() < maxCount;
            });
```

Just I am not sure whether this is more readable than a loop.

Comment: I tend to think of predicates as pure functions, so this is less readable to me. The `[&]` is a quick giveaway that this is not pure, though.

Comment: @MSalters: Not even sure it is valid, if compiler is allowed to use parallel policy under hood.

Comment: @Jarod42 The version of `std::all_of` without execution policy parameter requires an input iterator.

Comment: Couldn't it have dispatch for random iterator then?